# Kendo MVC batch editing change row color or focus

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am a new babie for Kendo UI for MVC, I am trying to customise row color when doing batch editing for a grid, I looked in the internet but couldn't find any info.  After editing a cell for batch editing grid by default Kendo add a small red spot at the top left hand side of the cell , what I want to achieve after editing any cell the whole row for that record change change it color. I would like to change  the row to green  for example to give the user more visibility what row have been edited before click save. I would really app if someone could help me.

code

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MvcKendo.Models.Availablity>().Name("grid")

.Columns( columns => {
    columns.Bound(c => c.Id);
    columns.Bound(c => c.TimeFrom);
    columns.Bound(c => c.TimeTo);
})
.DataSource(datasource => datasource.Ajax().PageSize(5)
.Read("GetDataAvailablity","Home"))
.ClientDetailTemplateId("template")   
 )

<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
        .Name("tabStrip_#=Id#")
        .SelectedIndex(0)
        .Animation(animation => animation.Open(open => open.Fade(FadeDirection.In)))
        .Items(items =>
        {
            items.Add().Text("TimeSheet Details").Content(@<text>@TimeSheetDetails()</text>);             
        })
    .ToClientTemplate()
)
```

```
 @helper TimeSheetDetails()
 {
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MvcKendo.Models.TimeSheet>()
.Name("grid_#=Id#")
         .Events(e => {
             e.DataBound("onDataBound");
             e.Change("ChangeEvent");
         })
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(t => t.Id);
        columns.Bound(t => t.WardName);
    })
    .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .ToolBar(tb=>tb.Save())
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax().Batch(true)
        .PageSize(5)
            .Model(model=>model.Id(x=>x.Id))
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetDataTimeSheet", "Home", new { Id = "#=Id#" }))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Editing_Update", "Home"))
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))

    )
.Pageable().Sortable().ToClientTemplate()
)
![enter image description here][2]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the save event in Kendo grid to achieve this

C#

```
.Events(events => events.Save("onSave")
```

Javascript

```
function(e) {
    $(e.container).closest("tr").css("background-color","lightgreen");
 }
```

[Here's the fiddle for the sample in JS](http://dojo.telerik.com/Ipixo)